# How can I retrieve the user password of a network shared pc

Tags: windows-7, networking, passwords, network-shares

As you can infer from the title itself, I need to retrieve the password which I entered a while ago and forgot. Long story short, how can I retrieve the user name and password of the PC that my PC connects without asking credentials?

I'd be grateful for any answers, thanks for helping

P.S. I'm using Windows 7 with SP1 updates installed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### How can I retrieve the user name and password of the PC that my PC connects to?

You can use [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) [Network Password Recovery](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html):

> When you connect to a network share on your LAN or to your .NET
> Passport account, Windows allows you to save your password in order to
> use it in each time that you connect the remote server. This utility
> recovers all network passwords stored on your system for the current
> logged-on user. It can also recover the passwords stored in
> Credentials file of external drive, as long as you know the last
> log-on password.
>
> Which passwords can this utility recover?
>
> - Login passwords of remote computers on your LAN.
> - Passwords of mail accounts on exchange server (stored by Microsoft Outlook)
> - Password of MSN Messenger / Windows Messenger accounts
> - Internet Explorer 7.x and 8.x: passwords of password-protected Web sites ("Basic Authentication" or "Digest Access Authentication")
> - The item name of IE7 passwords always begin with "Microsoft_WinInet" prefix.
> - The passwords stored by Remote Desktop 6.
>
> [image]

Source [Network Password Recovery](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way, I am just an end user of their software.

Comment: I just tried this tool on 2 totally different windows 10 systems and result was none, even there are passwords saved (and yes, I did run it as administrator, with intent) ... the list was empty and I can do NOTHING to retrieve any password, I kinda guess that this was *still* working on early windows 10 versions but not on latest ... sorry, but the answer is not working anymore :((

Comment: @THESorcerer It didn't work for me initially, but it did when I went to Advanced Options and selected my user profile.

Comment: Doesn't even run on current versions of W10.

Comment: The company should pay you for this kind of ads :P

Comment: Reported virus in this app...

Comment: @Li-chihWu Most anti virus programs report any password revealing software as false positives as "they could be used for hacking".

Comment: Worked for me on latest Win10. Freeware. Be sure to download the right version and check the instructions